# Prove that all contractible spaces are simply connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Prove that all contractible spaces are simply connected.

It's simple to prove that the space is pathwise connected. But, how can I prove that the fundamental group is trivial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental group is homotopy invariant.

Comment: How can I prove that the fundamental group is trivial?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a contractible space and what homotopy invariance means?

Comment: Contractible spaces yes, I know. But, homotopy invariance not yet. I'm a student of math and I am studying algebraic topology. I starded to study it one month ago.

Comment: Take a loop $f:[0,1] \to X$.  Contractibility of $X$ is equivalent to every map $Y \to X$ being null-homotopic so in particular $f$ is null-homotopic.  So the fundamental group consists of the single element which is the class of a constant map.

Comment: @Adeel Thank's!

Answer (score 4):

Any closed curve can be contracted like the space.